# how to get executable application from .bin files

Tags: windows, compilation

whene I extract a win32 application file.exe with (ressourcextract) I got .bin + .bmp and .txt files.
after some changes in one .bin file how to get my .exe application again , what must i do ? compile or assembly and how ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

possible dupe of: [Replacing Bitmap Resource in exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171624/replacing-bitmap-resource-in-exe)

You can undoubtedly find a tool to do so, but since this is a programming forum, these are the main APIs you would use:

[BeginUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648030.aspx), [UpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049.aspx), and [EndUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648032.aspx).

[Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648008.aspx)

For additional reference/information, here is the spec for the PE file format:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx